# Assume $\int_a^b (f-\lambda g)^2=0$. Then $\lambda=\frac{\int_a^b fg}{\int_a^b g^2}$. Sub $\lambda$ into first equation. How do we know it's zero?

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the function $$(f-\lambda g)^2\geq 0\tag{1}$$ where $f$ and $g$ are any functions and $\lambda$ is some number, and the integral

$$\int_a^b (f-\lambda g)^2\tag{2}\geq 0$$

We can write this as
$$\int_a^b f^2 -\lambda \cdot 2\int_a^b fg+\lambda^2\int_a^bg^2 \geq 0$$

Note that since this quadratic is non-negative, if it has a root then that root is unique, hence the discriminant is $0$.

$$\int_a^b f^2 -\lambda \cdot 2\int_a^b fg+\lambda^2\int_a^bg^2=0\tag{3}$$

$$\Delta=4\left (\int_a^b fg \right)^2-4\left (\int_a^bg^2 \right) \left ( \int_a^b f^2 \right )=0$$

$$\implies \lambda=\frac{\int_a^b fg}{\int_a^b g^2}$$

But now let's assume that we are starting with $(2)$ and we substitute this $\lambda$ into $(2)$.

$$\int_a^b (f-\lambda g)^2 = \int_a^b \left (f-\frac{\int_a^b fg}{\int_a^b g^2}g \right )^2$$

$$=\int_a^bf^2-\int_a^b \left ( 2fg \frac{\int_a^b fg}{\int_a^b g^2}\right ) +\int_a^b \left (\frac{\int_a^b fg}{\int_a^b g^2} \right)^2 g^2$$

$$= \int_a^b f^2 - 2\left ( \frac{\int_a^b fg}{\int_a^b g^2}\right )\cdot \int_a^b fg + \left ( \frac{\int_a^b fg}{\int_a^b g^2} \right )^2 \int_a^b g^2$$

$$=\int_a^b f^2 - 2 \frac{\left ( \int_a^b fg \right )^2}{\int_a^b g^2}+\frac{\left ( \int_a^b fg \right )^2}{\int_a^b g^2}$$

$$= \int_a^b f^2 -\frac{\left ( \int_a^b fg \right )^2}{\int_a^b g^2}$$

$$=\frac{\int_a^b f^2 \int_a^b g^2 - \left ( \int_a^b fg \right )^2}{\int_a^b g^2}\tag{4}$$

How come we don't obtain $0$, or how do we now that $(4)$ is zero?

Comment: Because the solution to $\int_a^b (f-\lambda g)^2 = 0$ is the specific $\lambda$ we found. Thus, if we take this specific $\lambda$ and insert it into $\int_a^b (f-\lambda g)^2$ we should get zero, no?

Comment: You dont have the correct  value of $\lambda$. You have to solve a quadratic to get the exact value of $\lambda$.

Comment: My value of $\lambda$ comes from solving the quadratic $(3)$. It works, given the assumption that $\Delta=0$. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Why do you even mean  by Assume $\Delta=0$. You cannot assume  that.

Comment: Actually $f-\lambda g=0$ almost everywhere  which gives $\lambda = \pm \sqrt {\frac {\int f^{2}} {\int g^{2}}}$.

Comment: I think the confusion is that for this question I am specifically interested in the case where $\int_a^b  (f-\lambda g)^2=0$. This is a quadratic in $\lambda$. Then $\Delta$ must be zero, which leads to the solution in $\lambda$ that I found. I then tried to start over at the initial expression $\int_a^b  (f-\lambda g)^2$ and just plug in the $\lambda$ that I found by assuming $\Delta=0$. The resulting expression only equals zero with the assumption that what we called $\Delta$ previously is zero.

Comment: If  a quadratic has  a **unique** solution then  $\Delta=0$. Here there are two values for $\lambda$.

Comment: Actually $\Delta=0$ isn't really an assumption right. It is a consequence of the assumption that $\int_a^b (f-\lambda g)^2=0$.

Comment: From your comments it looks like you jumped from "quadratic has a root" to "discriminant must be zero". That's just not valid. So no, it is not a consequence of that assumption

Comment: In this particular example, since $(f-\lambda g)^2 \geq 0$, then $\int_a^b (f-\lambda g)^2 \geq 0$. Therefore, we have two possible cases. Either the quadratic is $>0$ in which case the discriminant must be $<0$, or the quadratic has a (unique) root, in which case the discriminant must be $0$. The reason the root must be unique is that the quadratic is non-negative for all values of $x$. So, in general you are right, we can't make the jump from "a quadratic has a root" to "the discriminant must be zero". But if we know that the quadratic is non-negative we can.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Can you point to a single passage that is incorrect? See Calculus by Michael Spivak, Chapter 13, problem 39. Your comment is vague. I guess you prefer writing comments instead of answers since the latter can be downvoted but the former cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a simpler example

$$y(x)=x^2+bx+c=0\tag{1}$$

$$\Delta=b^2-4c$$

Assume $\Delta=0 \implies b^2=4c$.

Then $x=\frac{-b}{2}$ is the solution to $(1)$.

Note that this solution relies on our assumption that $b^2=4c$.

Okay, now start over with just $y(x)=x^2+bx+c$, no assumptions.

If we plug in $x=\frac{-b}{2}$ then we have

$$y\left (\frac{-b}{2}\right )=c-\frac{b^2}{4}$$

This $x$ isn't a solution unless we impose the assumption that $b^2=4c$.

In the original question we have exactly the same situation.

$\lambda = \frac{\int_a^b fg}{\int_a^b g^2}$ being a solution to $\lambda^2 \int_a^b g^2 -2\lambda \int_a^b fg+ \int_a^b f^2$ relied on an assumption, namely that $\Delta=0 \implies (\int_a^b fg)^2=\int_a^b g^2 \int_a^b f^2$.

So we can't just start over and plug in $\lambda$. We need the extra assumption.